# Variavel PHP no JS dentro do While

Tags: php, javascript, json, chartjs

Estou criando um grafico usando Chart.js e PHP, Gostaria que o valor viesse de um array em PHP com o indice de uma variavel do JS.
Este é o código do que eu tentei fazer.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
var ctx = document.getElementById("piechart").getContext("2d");
var data = [];
var i = 0;

while(i <= <?print $ind;?>)
{
data.push({
    <?$variavelphp = "<script>document.write(i)</script>";?>
    value: <?print $array[$variavelphp];?>,
    color:"#F7464A",
    highlight: "#FF5A5E",
    label: "Red"
});
i++;
}
}

var options = {
animateScale: false
};

var myNewChart = new Chart(ctx).Pie(data,options);

</script>
```

Comment: qual o problema que você está encontrando? seja mais claro com sua duvida por favor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O PHP executa primeiro, e só quando ele termina é que o JS será executado. O PHP roda no servidor, e o JS no cliente (browser). Sugiro que você monte a estrutura de dados no PHP, e passe isso pronto pro JS. Algo assim (supondo que `$ind` esteja declarado e tenha um valor numérico):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var ctx = document.getElementById("piechart").getContext("2d");
var data = [];
var i = 0;

<?php
$dados = array();
while($i <= $ind)
{
    $dados[] = array(
        "value" => $array($i), 
        "color" => "#F7464A",
        "highlight" => "#FF5A5E",
        "label" => "Red"
    );

    $i++;
}
?>

var options = {
    animateScale: false
};

var myNewChart = new Chart(ctx).Pie(<?php echo json_encode($dados) ?>, options);

</script>
```

Comment: Não funcionou.
O gráfico não é exibido.

Comment: É que na pergunta não está claro qual dado você quer mostrar. Eu *supus* que fosse `array[$i]`. Você precisa explicar melhor qual é o dado e de onde ele vem